# How to convert the time to string or integer

Tags: java, text, time, integer, tostring

I am facing a problem by storing the time from the code generated below to either integer or text.

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;

public class GetCurrentTimeStamp 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
        System.out.println(new Timestamp(date.getTime())); // need to store in a variables or INT.
    }
}
```

the output of this code is as below

```
2010-03-08 14:59:30.252
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you need to represent date as string or timestamp as string, so I did both :

```
     /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

         java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();

         //date to String
         String dateToString = date.toString();

         System.out.println("Date to String:      "+ dateToString);

         //formated date as String
         new SimpleDateFormat();
         SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
         String dateAsString = sdf.format(date);

         System.out.println("Formatted date:      "+ dateAsString);

         //time stamp to string
         Timestamp timeStamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
         String timeStampToString = timeStamp.toString();

         System.out.println("Timestamp to String: "+ timeStampToString);
    }
```

output is:

```
 Date to String:      Mon Aug 31 20:16:19 IDT 2015
 Formatted date:      2015-08-31 20:16:19
 Timestamp to String: 2015-08-31 20:16:19.736
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `new Timestamp`:

```
import java.util.Date;

public class GetCurrentTimeStamp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
        System.out.println(date.getTime()); // 1440948253205
    }
}
```

Note that `int` is too small to store the `Date`. You need a `long` variable.

Comment: by the way, i need to store the date in text , how can i achieve by the way? i mean how could i store the date in a variable?
*the date are not suppose to be 1440948253205

Comment: @calvinern if `date.toString()` isn't right for you, you can use a `SimpleDateFormat` to make it what ever you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
```

//time 21:57:54